# Broken query results with oracle instant client over occi

Tags: oracle, occi, instantclient

I am writing an occi based MFC Win32 application and wanted to deploy it with the oracle instant client in version 11.2.

The whole software works fine with the full client. With the instant client, the same queries work as well - but in some cases I get broken results (wrong data) - with no error message. In these cases, quite large HUGEBLOB entries are selected.

Has somebody experienced something similar? It would make me happy not to need the oracle full client.